# Suitable Control for displaying various game levels in a WP8 App

Tags: app

There is a mobile game on which I am working. It has various difficulty sections and each section has numerous levels, 250 levels in each section precisely.

Now, I need a suitable control which can display all the levels and by tapping on a certain level's button/icon, the user is able to move on and play that level.

I tried using a simple ScrollViewer(ScrollBar), but that is way too much scrolling for the user even if I display 10 levels in a single row.

Is there any inbuilt/existing control in WP that I can use to solve my problem?

P.S. Do remember, there are more than 250 levels that need to be displayed.

Comment: I'm migrating this to UX as it is an interface question much more than a graphic design question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the levels in a table, where scrolling up and down scrolls through the levels and scrolling left and right changes the section

[image: Level viewer]

Comment: This is what I have seem a lot of apps with levels do, never 250 but it should work fine. If you want to avoid scrolling you could have the right arrow lead to "Hard Levels Pt. 2" etc.